# What kind of fish did I see in waters off a tropical island in the Philippines?

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology

Found this while diving in the southern Philippines.
[image]

Comment: The downvote was not by me however plz provide more information about its habitat , size and description. if possible provide clearer picture.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused you need not give an explanation for your votes (or for not voting).

Answer (score 2):

This is a Blackspotted puffer, [Arothron nigropunctatus](http://www.fishbase.org/summary/Arothron-nigropunctatus.html) a commonly found fish on coral reefs in the Philippines. Although this species has a large color variation, the photos provided show common coloration (white body with black spots, a large black area around the dorsal ray). The white strip above the mouth is also a commonly found characteristic of this species, along with a face and snout that resembles a dog.

[image: CC- Photo by: John E. Randall]
*CC- Attribution - Photo by John E. Randall*